# Compute the integral $\int_{S^2} zdx\wedge dy$ in two ways

Tags: differential-topology

Compute the integral $\int_{S^2}  zdx\wedge dy$ in two ways: First using spherical coordinates and second using the parameterization of the hemispheres using square roots.

Comment: it is a nice problem... what had you done so far?

Comment: I really do not know where to begin.... I am totally stuck. of course I know the spherical coordinates  $x=r\sin\theta \cos\varphi,~ y=r \sin\theta\sin\varphi, ~ z=r\cos\theta$.